# Android/Java - Wait for AsyncTask to end before performing next function

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm creating an app which'll show a list of configured Wi-Fi networks in its `MainActivity`. Now, before fetching the list of configured networks, my app checks if Wi-Fi is turned on. If not, it shows an `AlertDialog` containing a **"Turn on Wi-Fi"** `Button` which triggers an `AsyncTask` that turns on the Wi-Fi.

Now, I'm using this code to fetch the list of configured Wi-Fi networks

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private ArrayList<String> getAvailableNetworks() {

    manager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    availableNetworks = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (!manager.isWifiEnabled()) {
        showDialog(2);
    }

    if (manager.isWifiEnabled()) {

        configuredNetworks = manager.getConfiguredNetworks();

        for (int i = 0; i < configuredNetworks.size(); i++) {
                    availableNetworks.add(configuredNetworks.get(i).SSID.replaceAll("\"", ""));
        }
    }

    return availableNetworks;
}
```

Now, the problem is that when the app finds out that the Wi-Fi is turned off, it just shows the `AlertDialog` using `showDialog(2);` and moves on to the next line of code which leaves the list of configured networks completely blank.

How do I get it to wait until the `AsyncTask` finishes turning on Wi-Fi before it moves on to the next line of code?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can use if-else here and also place the contents of you second if inside a listener for wifi state change and run the code when it is connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start an Indeterminate Progress Dialog (unCancelable) at OnPreExecute and then dismiss it in onPostExecute

And if you don't want the code to get started executing before the asyncTask gets Completed, just put that code in onPostExecute method of AsyncTask

Comment: I'm sorry. I still don't get it, how'll that keep the app from moving on to the next line of code until the `AsyncTask` is finished?

Comment: So why don't you put the code in onPostExecute which you want to execute after asyncTask?

Comment: No sir. For some reason or other, the list remains empty even after putting the code in the `onPreExecute` section of my `AsyncTask`

Comment: Sorry, I had put the code in `onPostExecute` only. I made a mistake while typing the comment.

Comment: That's strange would you post the code you are putting in onPostExecute?

Comment: Um.... I'm on mobile right now. I'll post it after, say, 22:30(Indian Standard Time), okay?

Comment: no problem, btw try debugging your code too, sometimes the problem isn't there where you think it is :)

Comment: I solved it! I added the mechanism of checking if the Wi-Fi is turned on in the `onCreate` section of my `MainActivity`. Thanks for your help!